# UIScrollView ignores frameLayoutGuide constraints on iOS 12 when built with iOS 14.1 SDK

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I just wasted an hour with what looks like an iOS 14 SDK regression when running on iOS 12 so I thought i'd post this in case it helps others.

**Summary**: When pinning the frame of the `UIScrollView` with the `frameLayoutGuide` as we've always done, this breaks on iOS 12 when the scrollview is contained within another view (in my case in a child viewcontroller, not sure if that matters).

**Setup**:
View setup, all views using autolayout:

```
UIView "scrollviewContainerView" [fixed/unchanging size]
 |
 \- UIScrollView "scrollView"
     |
     \ UIView "contentView"
```

Constraints that lead to Symptom:

1. scrollview's `frameLayoutGuide` pinned to top/bottom/leading/trailing of scrollviewContainerView
2. contentView pinned to top/bottom/leading/trailing of scrollview's `contentLayoutGuide`
3. because this is a vertical scrollview: contentView's `widthAnchor` pinned to scrollView's `frameLayoutGuide`

**Symptom**: On iOS 14, everything looks fine. On iOS 12 when scrolling, the size of the `UIScrollView` itself changes, seemingly ignoring the `frameLayoutGuide` constraints (even though they're still there: I couldn't see any difference when debugging the view hierarchy between iOS 12's resulting set of constraints and iOS 14). This makes things look very very broken.

Comment: typical... i spend a while typing this all up and a rando downvotes the entire thing with no reason given

Comment: This is a little confusing... you should not constrain the Frame Layout Guide in that way. When you constrain the scroll view's ***frame*** to the `scrollviewContainerView`, the scroll view automatically defines its `.frameLayoutGuide`. It looks like you're trying to do it the other way around.

Comment: Hi @DonMag ah, maybe I totally misunderstood `frameLayoutGuide` ... if it isn't supposed to be used to define the frame of the scrollview, what is it for? Or are you saying it is defining the frame of the scrollview, but only descendants/subviews should use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help understand `UIScrollView`, `Frame Layout Guide` and `Content Layout Guide`...

`Frame Layout Guide` and `Content Layout Guide` were introduced in iOS 11, in part to eliminate the ambiguity of frame vs content, as well as to allow adding "non-scrolling" elements to the scroll view.

For each of the following examples, I'm adding and constraining the scroll view like this:

```
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    
    // respect safe area
    let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        // constrain scrollView 20-pts on each side
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        
    ])
    
    // so we can see the scroll view's frame
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
```

Now, consider the "old" way of adding content:

```
    // call a func to get a vertical stack view with 30 labels
    let stackView = createStackView()
    
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        // old method
        // constrain stack view to scroll view itself
        //  this defines the "scrollable" content
        
        // stack view Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom to scroll view
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        
        // we want vertical scrolling, so we want our content to be only as wide as
        // the scroll view itself
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        
    ])
```

Fairly straightforward, although a little ambiguous. Am I making the stack view only as tall as the scroll view, by constraining its bottom anchor? That's what I'd expect if it's a subview of any other `UIView`!

So, consider the "new" way of doing it:

```
    // call a func to get a vertical stack view with 30 labels
    let stackView = createStackView()
    
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    
    let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
    let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        // constrain stack view to scroll view's Content Layout Guide
        //  this defines the "scrollable" content
        
        // stack view Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom to scroll view's Content Layout Guide
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        
        // we want vertical scrolling, so we want our content to be only as wide as
        //  the scroll view's Frame Layout Guide
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        
    ])
```

Now, it's very clear that I am using the stack view to define the "scrollable content" by constraining it to the `.contentLayoutGuide` and using the scroll view's actual **frame** (its `.frameLayoutGuide`) to define the stack view's width.

In addition, suppose I want a UI element - such as an image view - to be *inside* the scroll view, but I don't want it to scroll? The "old way" would require adding the image view as a *sibling* view overlaid on top of the scroll view.

But now, by using `.frameLayoutGuide`, I can add it as a "non-scrolling" element inside the scroll view:

```
    guard let img = UIImage(named: "scrollSample") else {
        fatalError("could not load image")
    }
    let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)
    imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        // constrain image view to the Frame Layout Guide
        //  at top-right, with 20-pts Top / Trailing "padding"
        imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        // 120 x 120 pts
        imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
        imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
        
    ])
```

Now, any elements I constrain to the scrollView's `.contentLayoutGuide` will scroll, but the image view constrained to the scrollView's `.frameLayoutGuide` will remain in place.

Comment: Excellent, thank you -- I was indeed using `frameLayoutGuide` incorrectly. As your answer shows, this is logically supposed to be used by scrollview's subviews/descendants. **For others: when defining the UIScrollView's position in its superview, do not use `frameLayoutGuide`**

Comment: @xaphod - you should provide this as an answer as this was the problem I was having with my scrollviews for the past 3-4 days.