# Label and TextView overflows Scroll View horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a Scroll View, in which I have a Stack View. In the Stack View I have arranged subviews of either UITextView or UILabel elements.
All is done programmatically, without storyboard.

The Scroll View appears and I can scroll it nicely. But unfortunately it scrolls not only vertically (top to bottom) but also horizontally (to the right, out the screen) which I don't want to (this is the reason I have numberOfLines set on the UILabel too, tried to set equal width to the scroll and stack views as the stack view's left/right attributes are connected to the view).

If it's important, this function is called either in viewDidLoad or upon touching a button later.

```
    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    let leftConstraintScroll = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let rightConstraintScroll = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraintScroll = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: selectedTabIndicator, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    let bottomConstraintScroll = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: editButton, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraints([leftConstraintScroll, rightConstraintScroll, topConstraintScroll, bottomConstraintScroll])

    stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 10
    stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    stackView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 10, bottom: 5, trailing: 10)

    // Several elements are added like this (UITextView):
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    textView.backgroundColor = Constants.COLOR_P
    textView.textColor = .black
    textView.text = "XXX"
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(textView)

    // Or UILabel:
    var label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textAlignment = .justified
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .justified
    paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 15
    let hyphenAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "XXXXX", attributes: hyphenAttribute)
    label.attributedText = attributedString
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    scrollView.addConstraints([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint, bottomConstraint])
```

Note: selectedTabIndicator and editButton are above and below the scroll view respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note: when posting code, post some **actual** code. Your code refers to `scrollView` and `recipeScrollView` which, I assume, are the same scroll view. Also, try to post complete information - your code also refers to `selectedTabIndicator` and `editButton`, neither of which have been identified nor described in your question.

Second note: start using more modern constraint syntax. For example:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    recipeScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
    recipeScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
    recipeScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectedTabIndicator.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0),
    recipeScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editButton.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
])
```

is much easier to use (and to read) than:

```
let leftConstraintScroll = NSLayoutConstraint(item: recipeScrollView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let rightConstraintScroll = NSLayoutConstraint(item: recipeScrollView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let topConstraintScroll = NSLayoutConstraint(item: recipeScrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: selectedTabIndicator, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
let bottomConstraintScroll = NSLayoutConstraint(item: recipeScrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: editButton, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraints([leftConstraintScroll, rightConstraintScroll, topConstraintScroll, bottomConstraintScroll])
```

Third note: respect the Safe Area... so your leading constraint should be:

```
recipeScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
```

and so on.

Fourth note: constrain your scroll view's content to the `.contentLayoutGuide`, not to the scroll view itself.

To solve your "horizontal scrolling" issue, instead of setting the `label` and `textView` widths, set the width of the stack view relative to the scroll view's `.frameLayoutGuide`:

```
stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: recipeScrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0)
```

Here is your code, edited with those tips. I put a blue view near the top to be the `selectedTabIndicator` and a blue button near the bottom to be the `editButton`:

```
class AnotherScrollViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    var recipeScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var stackView: UIStackView!
    var textView: UITextView!

    var selectedTabIndicator: UIView!
    var editButton: UIButton!
    
    var editButtonBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        selectedTabIndicator = UIView()
        selectedTabIndicator.backgroundColor = .blue
        selectedTabIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(selectedTabIndicator)
        
        editButton = UIButton()
        editButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        editButton.setTitle("Edit", for: [])
        editButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(editButton)
        
        recipeScrollView = UIScrollView()
        recipeScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(recipeScrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        editButtonBottom = editButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            selectedTabIndicator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            selectedTabIndicator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            selectedTabIndicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            selectedTabIndicator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4.0),
            
            //editButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            editButtonBottom,
            editButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            recipeScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectedTabIndicator.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            recipeScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            recipeScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            recipeScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editButton.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])

        stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 10
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stackView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 10, bottom: 5, trailing: 10)
        
        // Several elements are added like this (UITextView):
        textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        textView.backgroundColor = .cyan // Constants.COLOR_P
        textView.textColor = .black
        textView.text = "XXX"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textView)
        
        // Or UILabel:
        var label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .justified
        label.backgroundColor = .green  // so we can easily see the label frame
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .justified
        paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0
        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
        paragraphStyle.headIndent = 15
        let hyphenAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
        let labelString = "This is the string for the label. It will wrap if it is too long to fit in the allocated width."
        //let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "XXXXX", attributes: hyphenAttribute)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelString, attributes: hyphenAttribute)
        label.attributedText = attributedString
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

        recipeScrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        let contentG = recipeScrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = recipeScrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])

        recipeScrollView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
        
        editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.editButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func editButtonTapped() -> Void {
        if textView.isFirstResponder {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
        guard let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
        
        let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue
        let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)
        print(keyboardViewEndFrame.height)
        var c: CGFloat = -4.0
        if notification.name != UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
            c -= (keyboardViewEndFrame.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
        }
        
        editButtonBottom.constant = c
        
        editButton.setTitle(c == -4 ? "Edit" : "Done", for: [])
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps a lot, updated my code based on your suggestions and worked as a charm.
1st note: you are right, sorry for that. I wanted to reduce the code, thought it will be easier to read...
2nd, 3rd notes: Thanks for the hints! I didn't know the difference between left/leading right/trailing before... Now read about it.
4th note: It works, but may I ask you please to explain a bit better this contantLayoutGuide and frameLayoutGuide? I don't see why they are needed and what they do.

Comment: @zdtorok - hopefully, this answer helps explain `contentLayoutGuide` and `frameLayoutGuide`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64560447/6257435

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it, maybe not the best solution, so I leave the question still open for a while, for better solutions.

Basically, I provided a widthAnchor constraint to each UILabel and UITextView when I created them, before adding them to the stack view.

```
label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20).isActive = true
```